# Find child elements in a WPF ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, datatemplate

Given a populated `ListView`, how do I iterate through each bound *template* and pluck out the contained `ComboBox` (or any other control contained in `DataTemplate`)?

```
<ListView x:Name="lstCommands">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid x:Name="gridInputs">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbInputCmd" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource inputData}}" Tag="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, avoid doing so unless you really need to. If you absolutely must, you can use [`DataTemplate.FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx), where the templated parent is the `ListViewItem` generated by the `ListView`. To get the `ListViewItem`, use the `ListView`'s `ItemContainerGenerator`.

Update: the reason I suggest avoiding this approach wherever possible is because it creates more tightly-coupled, brittle code. The OP didn't mention why he wanted to do what he was asking, but I suspect he could achieve his goal by more idiomatic means, such as with bindings.

Comment: Hi! iam quite new in wpf. And i wonder what is the reason for not doing it. Because i have a similar problem. I have a listview with items and comboboxes inside them. And a button outside the listview with saves the selected values in the comboxes.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart Good information, but not terribly helpful just saying "don't do it." The reasons aren't in the MSDN documentation you linked to, so everyone is just left wondering what you know, but what we don't.

Comment: Also, according to the documentation linked to in the question, you actually use the ContentPresenter as the templatedParent argument in FindName(). Using the ListeViewItem causes exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

is simple 
just do this

```
    <ListViewItem Name="mainiterm" Style="{ StaticResource inboxlst}" Selected="ListViewItem_Selected_1">
            <Canvas Style="{StaticResource inboxcanvas}">
                    <Label Name="namelabel"  Content="lalallala1" Style="{StaticResource inboxlabel1}" />
                <Label  Content="lalallala" Style="{StaticResource inboxlabel2}"/>
              </Canvas>
        </ListViewItem>
```

and vb

```
 Dim r = mlistview.Items.GetItemAt(i)
    Dim textYear As Label = Nothing
    Dim s As Canvas = r.Content
    Dim a As Label = s.Children.Item(1)
    a.Content = "Disconnected"
```

> a is a label, s is a cavas

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the `LogicalTreeHelper` or `VisualTreeHelper` which lets you query an object for its children, but if you were binding your combo boxes to the item your list view is displaying you would not have to worry about 'getting' them at all.

Then you could just look at your item.

Any time you find yourself walking the visual or logical tree looking for elements which exist in your ui, so that you can get their values, ask yourself 'what am i missing here' 'why isnt my business (or view model) being updated with relevant data when the user interacts with the ui?'

For the example above I would build a view model that had two properties, a String (for your label) and a SelectedItem (that you could bind your combo box selected item to). its easier, more robust and it stops you having to trawl through the visual elements. one of the beautiful things about xaml/wpf is that it seperates your logic from your view. what you are suggesting will break this model. You will entangle the view with your logic and from there on it gets messy...